# ¿Cómo hago para llenar un array con números ingresados en un formulario? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, array, entrada

Necesito llenar 5 posiciones de un `array` con números ingresados en un `input` por el usuario, el problema es que no se como insertarlos en el array, he logrado hacer esto:

```js
var numeros = new Array(5);
```

```html
<input type="number" name="array">
```

Answer (score 3):

Para llenar el `array` podrías capturar el valor del `input` cuando se detecte el cambio de valor (usando el evento `change`) y luego ese valor lo agregar al `array` usando la función `push()` de JavaScript.

Agregué una condición para que una vez el `array` tenga un `length` de 5 no permita agregar más valores.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('change', llenarArray, false);

var numeros = Array();

function llenarArray(){
    var valor = input.value;

    if(numeros.length >= 4){
        alert('Array completamente lleno ' + numeros);
        input.value = '';
    }else{
        numeros.push(Number(valor));
        alert('Se agregó un valor nuevo al array ' + numeros);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="array">
```

Comment: y con javascript puro se puede?

Comment: @mati el ejemplo que te acabo de hacer es JavaScript nativo (puro) sin librerías !

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
var b = document.getElementById("a"), d = [];
b.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
var s = e.target.value.length;
if(s === 5) {
d = d.concat(e.target.value.split(""));
console.log(d);
}
});
});
```

```html
<input id="a" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa números">
```